# How to check if a file is pkcs#8 DER format in Java?

Tags: java, der, pkcs#8

I need to check if a file is pkcs#8 DER format in Java when uploading the file, I think maybe PKCS8EncodedKeySpec and getFormat() can be used.

```
class FileFormatePkcs8{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = args[0];
        try {
            File f = new File(filename);
            byte[] encodedKey = new byte[(int)f.length()];
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8Key = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
            if(pkcs8Key.getFormat().equals("PKCS#8")) {
                System.out.println("It's pkcs8.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("It's not pkcs8.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("exception:"+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

All the files input will get the "It's pkcs8." result. I realize "PKCS8EncodedKeySpec" will create the pkcs#8 key, but I don't know using which class to replace it.

Note that: both of PKCS#8 and DER need to be check, so I think org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser can be ignored. Or am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't actually read the contents of the file at all. You just create an empty buffer the same *size* as the file. Since this buffer doesn't contain any data, the non-present data is not in PKCS8 format, nor JKS format, nor Bitcoin wallet format, nor any other format. (Note instead of multiple steps, you can just use `byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename))`).

Second, [there are two PKCS8 DER formats](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5208).

OOTB Java visibly supports PKCS8-unencrypted (clear) `PrivateKeyInfo` *only* if you know the algorithm to which the key applies (RSA, DSA, ECDSA/ECDH, etc). If you do, simply call `KeyFactory.getInstance` for that algorithm, then call `.generatePrivateKey` with a `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` containing the (purported) PKCS8-clear, and if it returns an appropriate subclass of PrivateKey (and doesn't throw an exception) then the data was in fact PKCS8-clear *and* for that algorithm. If you don't know the algorithm but only a limited set are permitted or possible, you can simply try each in turn and see if any (and which) works.

Otherwise, you must either parse the ASN.1 yourself (possible, but nontrivial), or use BouncyCastle (but not the PEM part): call `org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(der)` and if it succeeds the input data either is PKCS8-clear or a very good imitation.

For PKCS8-encrypted, Java *does* expose [`javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D)); just invoke the constructor on the data and if it doesn't throw the data looked like PKCS8-encrypted. This does not check however that this data can be decrypted and when decrypted is actually a privatekey as it should be; for that if you know the password use `epki.getKeySpec()` combined with checking the resulting purported PKCS8-clear as above.

Comment: The logic is correct, thank you very much. But i found that the logic for privateKeyInfo and encryptedPrivateKeyInfo can't check the DER format key which is converted from the PEM format. E.g. `openssl genrsa -out rsa_private_key.pem 1024; openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -in rsa_private_key.pem -outform DER -nocrypt -out pkcs8-noencryp1.der; openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -in rsa_private_key.pem -outform DER -v1 PBE-SHA1-3DES -out pkcs8-encryp.der`, the logic can check the `pkcs8-noencryp1.der` and `pkcs8-encryp.der`, but can't check the `pkcs8-noencryp-pem-to-der.der`.

Comment: The `pkcs8-noencryp-pem-to-der.der` is produced by `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -in rsa_private_key.pem -outform PEM -nocrypt -out pkcs8-noencryp.pem; openssl pkcs8 -outform der -in pkcs8-noencryp.pem -out pkcs8-noencryp-pem-to-der.der -nocrypt`, do you know what's the problem?

Comment: The commands in your second comment don't produce a PKCS8 file; in particular the second command doesn't have `-topk8` and writes a _legacy_ (PKCS1) DER file not a PKCS8 DER file. So there is no problem; the code is correctly detecting that the file is not PKCS8.

Comment: Awesome! That's it, thank you for your great help!